# How many $c$ for which equation $ax+(a + 1)y=c$ will have no positive integer solution?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

Suppose we are given an equation in $ax+(a + 1)y=c$

Now we have to find for how many values of $c$ where $c \in [1,\infty)$ will have no positive integral solution.

I'm new to diophantine equation, so I can't think of any approach. But can it be found mathematically?

Till now my approach is based on programming/brute force

I'm using a small function to check for all possible values.

```
void bruteforce(int a, int b, int n) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i * a <= n; i++) { 

        if ((n - (i * a)) % b == 0) { 
              if((i)>0 && ((n - (i * a)) / b)>0){
                 cout << "x = " << i << ", y = " << ; 
              }
            return; 
        } 
    } 

    cout << "Not Possible"; 
}
```

But how can i find it more mathematically?

Example -

$3x+4y$
This equation won't have any positive integer solution for $c∈\{1,2,5\}$

$4x+5y$ this equation won't have any positive integer solution for $c ∈ \{1,2,3,6,7,11\}$ so answer would be $6$

So answer comes as $^3C_2$ in first case and $^4C_2$ in second.

Comment: Show us your attempts

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880744/diophantine-equation-ax-by-c-has-an-integer-solution-x-0-y-0-if-and-onl

Comment: I've added my attempt. Also the question is for how many values of $c$ there won't be any positive integer solution.

Comment: there are infinite  numbers of  such $c$ for example  any prime numbers $p>\gcd(a,b).$

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add one more point. It's given that $b= a+1$, i.e  $a$ and $b$ are consecutive, from my brute force method i find the answer to be coming as aC2

Comment: I'm giving an example..
.
3x+4y This equation won't have any positive integer solution for {1,2,5} so the answer would be 3
.
4x+5y this equation won't have any positive integer solution for {1,2,3,6,7,11} so answer would be 6
.
So answer comes as 3C2 in first case and 4C2 in second

Comment: Can $a$ be non-positive ?

Comment: How do you achieve $3x+4y=4$ ???

Comment: It is unclear what is being asked. The question as posed asks "For a chosen positive integer $c$, can we always find $a,x,y$ that satisfy the relationships?" The answer to that, provided by many respondents, is YES. But the examples seem to imply that the question OP is really interested in is "For chosen positive integers $c,a$, can we always find $x,y$ that satisfy the relationships?" The answer to that question, by OP examples, is NO.

Answer (score 1):

The condition for the existence of integral solutions to $ax + by = c$ is $gcd(a, b) \; | \ c$. As the set $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite so we can always find infinite numbers which aren't multiples of $gcd(a, b)$.

Comment: With the latest edit, $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,a+1)=1$

Comment: Yes the GCD of consecutive number is 1, please look at the example which i added. There are some values of c such that the equation won't have any positive integer solution like 3x+4y=5

Answer (score 0):

My approach solves the equation over the integers, then tries to find a positive solution :

$x=-c$ and $y=c$ is a solution.

as $gcd(a,b)=1$, and $ab-ba=0$, all solutions to the inital equation are of the form $(-c-kb,c+ka)$ for an integer $k$.

assuming $a$ positive, both $x$ and $y$ are positive iff:

$$ \dfrac{-c}{a}< k <\dfrac{-c}{a+1}  $$

So a positive solution exists iff there is an integer between $\dfrac{c}{a+1}$ and $\dfrac{c}{a}$

I think your examples allow non-negative solutions (eg $4x+5y=5$ works for $x=0$ and $y=1$), but you might live (like myself) in a country where positive means $\geq 0$ (then change the $<$'s in my solution by $\leq$'s).

Answer (score 0):

The equation is

$$ax+(a+1)y=a(x+y)+y=az+y=c$$ where $z\ge2,y\ge1$.

Assuming $a\ge0$, There are solutions for all $c\ge2a+1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \ge 1$ and $y \ge 1$, then $c = ax+(a + 1)y \ge a(1)+(a+1)(1) = 2a+1$ Why does your program include $x=0$ and $y=0$ since $0$ is not a positive integer?